# C# Not Writing to Settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, settings

so I am writing a program in C# and I need it to save to custom Setting I made in the Settings designer. Here is a screenshot of the settings I have and here are a few examples of the way I am writing to the Settings.

[image: http://prntscr.com/4svc6g]

```
 private void txtUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.username = txtUsername.Text;
     }

 private void cbUpdate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.autoCheck = cbUpdate.Checked;
        }

//In another method \/\/
 if (Properties.Settings.Default.launchNumber == 0)
            {
                Settings form2 = new Settings();
                form2.Show();
                Properties.Settings.Default.launchNumber++;
            }
```

So I'm pretty stumped right now, it is reading the settings I manually set in the designer normal, it just won't write over them when I set the setting to another value. I'm pretty much just trying to find where I went wrong in changing the settings. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: As Saeb Amini points out you will have to call the Save() method. And when you do so, the changes are not reflected on your file in the assembly directory, but rather in the local app data directory since you have specified the scope to be 'user'... windows 7 local app data is C:\Users\'LOGGED IN USER'\AppData\Local\

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling `Save` after updating settings:

```
Settings.Default.Save()
```